# How many times the loop will execute in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How many times the for loop will be evaluated in the following in python?:

```
for i in range(0,10):
pass
```

Comment: 0 because of improper indentation.

Comment: Just try it out with `print(i)`?

Comment: Jayant, SO discourages discussion oriented questions. If you are coding something and want help with chosing best practice then post your code.

Comment: Don't be scared or discouraged, stack overflow is full of people who want to help. keep asking more questions. They are pouncing on you very hard i can see from the number of down votes. But don't be discouraged, keep asking questions and keep learning. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in range(0,10):
    print(i)
```

Will output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Now the OP will look at the last line and say: "Oh, I see, the loop is executed 9 times." ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For any range function that you use

```
 range(start,end)
```

it will iterate through the loop for **end-start** times, if there were no loop cutting statements like break.
In your case

```
range(0,10)
10-0 =10
```

So it will iterate for 10 times.